# Alfresco dashlet post form

Tags: alfresco-share

I have been searching google for a few days now and cant find any solution to my problem.

I have created a custom Alfresco Aukai dashlet and placed a form in it thus:

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare",
    "dijit/_WidgetBase",
    "alfresco/core/Core",
    "alfresco/core/I18nUtils",
    "alfresco/dashlets/Dashlet"],
function(declare, AlfCore, I18nUtils, Dashlet) {
    // First define a form...
    var form = {
        name: "alfresco/forms/Form",
        config: {
            showOkButton: true,
            okButtonLabel: "Save",
            showCancelButton: false,
            cancelButtonLabel: "Doesn't Matter",
            okButtonPublishTopic: "PUBLISH_TOPIC",
            okButtonPublishGlobal: true,
            widgets: []
        }
    };
// Define a text box...
    var textBox = {
        name: "alfresco/forms/controls/DojoValidationTextBox",
        config: {
            fieldId: "EMAIL",
            name: "email",
            label: "Contact",
            description: "Your e-mail address",
            placeHolder: "name@address.com",
            validationConfig: [
                {
                    validation: "regex",
                    regex: "^([0-9a-zA-Z]([-.w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-w]*[0-9a-zA-Z].)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})$",
                    errorMessage: "Valid E-mail Address Required"
                }
            ]
        }
    };
    form.config.widgets.push(textBox);
// Define a checkbox...
    var checkbox = {
        name: "alfresco/forms/controls/DojoCheckBox",
        config: {
            fieldId: "SHOW",
            name: "showEmail",
            label: "Show E-mail",
            description: "Uncheck to hide the e-mail field",
            value: true
        }
    };
    form.config.widgets.push(checkbox);
// Update the textbox to respond to checkbox changes...
    textBox.config.visibilityConfig = {
        initialValue: true,
        rules: [
            {
                targetId: "SHOW",
                is: [true]
            }
        ]
    };
    return declare([Dashlet], {
        /*
         * Add padding to the body.
         * smallpad (4px padding), mediumpad (10px padding - recommended) and largepad (16px padding)
         */
        additionalCssClasses: "mediumpad",
        /**
         * Explicit height in pixels of the Dashlet body.
         */
        bodyHeight: 200,
        /**
         * Id that will be used to store properties for this Dashlet.
         * i.e. the Dashlet height when using the resizer.
         */
        componentId: "component.messaging-dashlet",
        /**
         * The i18n scope to use for this Dashlet.
         */
        i18nScope: "dashlets.MessagingDashlet",
        /**
         * An array of the i18n files to use with this Dashlet.
         */
        i18nRequirements: [{i18nFile: "./i18n/MessagingDashlet.properties"}],
        /**
         * The widgets to be acting as title bar actions.
         */
        widgetsForTitleBarActions: [
            {
                id: "MESSAGING_DASHLET_ACTIONS",
                name: "alfresco/html/Label",
                config: {
                    label: "Title-bar actions"
                }
            }
        ],
        /**
         * The widgets to be placed in the top toolbar.
         */
        widgetsForToolbar: [
            {
                id: "MESSAGING_DASHLET_TOOLBAR",
                name: "alfresco/html/Label",
                config: {
                    label: "Toolbar"
                }
            }
        ],
        /**
         * The widgets to be placed in the body of the dashlet.
         */
        widgetsForBody: [
            {
                id: "HELLO_DASHLET_VERTICAL_LAYOUT",
                name: "alfresco/layout/VerticalWidgets",
                config: {
                    widgetWidth: 50,
                    widgets: [
                        form
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

The form is displayed but the Save button is inactive.

When checking with fire bug I am informed that there is no javascript on the page!

Apart from this every thing works fine even get the error message when an invalid email address is entered.

Any suggestions? Alternatively a working example of a form in a dashlet posting would be nice :)

I have looked into this further while trying to populate a select box with the OptionsService.

```
optionsConfig: {
    publishTopic: "ALF_GET_FORM_CONTROL_OPTIONS",
    publishPayload: {
        url: url.context + "/proxy/alfresco/api/people",
        itemsAttribute: "people",
        labelAttribute: "firstName",
        valueAttribute: "userName"
    }
```

In the debug I can see this but nothing happens over the wire, there is not corresponding request sent to the server!

This is the same issue I am getting with the post so this would suggest a more fundamental problem with my code.

Answer (score 0):

Your form does not have any widgets / controls defined.

```
okButtonPublishGlobal: true,
            widgets: []
```

Please refer simple CRUD example using aikau, http://www.codingfreaks.net/2015/03/aikau-form-example-for-simple-student.html

https://github.com/Alfresco/Aikau/blob/develop/aikau/src/main/resources/alfresco/reports/TopSiteContributorReport.js

[image]

Can you please look at this link?

Alfresco share is using  *Site Contributor Breakdown Dashlet*, with the input form controls using aikau.

Comment: Tried that and many other options. Completely rearanged code! Added widget and change widget type! Added services to all kinds of things.

In every either got dashlet that would not load due to error or a dashlet with the expected form which did not post!

Using both Firefox and Chrome debug dont wee anything happen when button is clicked :(

Comment: I must be missing something fundamental!
I have tried the example given as a guide but am getting nowhere. 
I think my problem is with the example being a report and doing the submit from an event on the pie chart where as I want to do the submit from the button on a form in a dashlet.
I am finding forms very confusing and the examples very limited.
My tasks is to produce a proof of concept using Alfresco as the basis for the replacement for a java system. The main issue with the Java system is document management which is definitely provided by Alfresco so no problem there.

Comment: We want to provide existing functionality in an Alfresco ways so that going forwards the new system can be maintained by a competent Alfresco developer.
So the plan for the POC is to migrate the messaging system to Alfresco.
This would be a dashlet that creates a document of type MESSAGE that is uneditable and only viewable by the person sending and receiving. Kind of like an in system SMS with the ability to attach documents. Its more complex than that but that the general idea.

Comment: Don't worry. Just attach the form UI screenshot and let me try to help you.